# Does Amazon CloudFormation make provision for deploying RDS instances to different environments in a Multi-AZ configuration?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I am trying to create Amazon RDS instances in different environments using CloudFormation templates. There is a Multi-AZ requirement in Prod, but other environments do not need Multi-AZ. This calls for a condition function in CloudFormation.

Based on the [RDS CloudFormation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html) and using the [if condition in CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if), the following should work in the template:

```
Conditions:
  IsProd: !Equals [ !Ref EnvironmentType, prod ]
...
Resources:
  MyRDSInstance:
    Properties:
      ...
      AvailabilityZone:
        !If [ IsProd, AWS::NoValue, af-south-1a ]
      ...
      MultiAZ: !If [ IsProd, true, false ]
```

When `IsProd` evaluates to:

- false, `AvailabilityZone: af-south-1a` and `MultiAZ: false`
- true, `AvailabilityZone` [is removed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20AWS%3A%3ANoValue%20pseudo%20parameter%20as%20a%20return%20value%20to%20remove%20the%20corresponding%20property.) and `MultiAZ: true`, which meets the requirement specified in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%27t%20set%20the%20AvailabilityZone%20parameter%20if%20the%20MultiAZ%20parameter%20is%20set%20to%20true.):

> You can't set the AvailabilityZone parameter if the MultiAZ parameter is set to true.

However, when trying to deploy the prod RDS instance, I still get the following error in CloudFormation when creating the stack, which then prevents the resources from being created at all:

> Requesting a specific availability zone is not valid for Multi-AZ instances. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: e6177fe4-4a4b-4db3-ba66-5f0e0f7218eb; Proxy: null)

I suspect this is a bug in AWS due to a recent change that was applied in the source code, even though it was related to the CDK and not CloudFormation:

- Issue: [Availability Zone parameter silently removed from stack when MultiAZ is true](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/10949)
- Fix committed on May 25, 2021: fix(rds): [Add exception throw when az is defined for multi-az db inst…](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/commit/fd8445ff1bf94b3dde26211c497bda7211b54dc0). I am getting the error thrown in this exact fix.

Could it be that CloudFormation is now not making provision for the `AWS::NoValue` pseudo parameter? If this is a bug in the source code, is there any way to get around this so I can still achieve Multi-AZ in the prod environment only?

Comment: TL;DR, the solution is to correct the pseudo parameter from `AWS::NoValue` to `!Ref AWS::NoValue`

Comment: Just to clarify, the CDK issue and PR mentioned are strictly related to CDK that produces CloudFormation code before applying it, but is not related with CloudFormation itself. CDK is a framework on top of CloudFormation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried to replicate the same at my end but in my case I was able to successfully create the RDS resource. I am attaching the template which I used for your reference.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  Description": "AWS CloudFormation Sample Template for creating an Amazon RDS DB instance: 
  Sample template showing how to create a DB instance with Enhanced Monitoring enabled. 
  **WARNING** This template creates an RDS DB instance. You will be billed for the AWS 
  resources used if you create a stack from this template.
Parameters:
  IsMultiAZ:
    Type: String
    Default: false
    AllowedValues: [true,false]
    Description: Please enter either "true" or "false"
  DBInstanceID:
    Default: mydbinstance
    Description: My database instance
    Type: String
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '63'
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*'
    ConstraintDescription: >-
      Must begin with a letter and must not end with a hyphen or contain two
      consecutive hyphens.
  DBName:
    Default: mydb
    Description: My database
    Type: String
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '64'
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*'
    ConstraintDescription: Must begin with a letter and contain only alphanumeric characters.
  DBInstanceClass:
    Default: db.m5.large
    Description: DB instance class
    Type: String
    ConstraintDescription: Must select a valid DB instance type.
  DBAllocatedStorage:
    Default: '50'
    Description: The size of the database (GiB)
    Type: Number
    MinValue: '20'
    MaxValue: '65536'
    ConstraintDescription: must be between 20 and 65536 GiB.
  DBUsername:
    NoEcho: 'true'
    Description: Username for MySQL database access
    Type: String
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '16'
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*'
    ConstraintDescription: must begin with a letter and contain only alphanumeric characters.
  DBPassword:
    NoEcho: 'true'
    Description: Password MySQL database access
    Type: String
    MinLength: '8'
    MaxLength: '41'
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z0-9]*'
    ConstraintDescription: must contain only alphanumeric characters.
Conditions:
  CheckIsMultiZone:
     !Equals [!Ref IsMultiAZ, true]

Resources:
  MyDB:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBInstance'
    Properties:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: !Ref DBInstanceID
      DBName: !Ref DBName
      DBInstanceClass: !Ref DBInstanceClass
      AllocatedStorage: !Ref DBAllocatedStorage
      Engine: MySQL
      EngineVersion: "8.0.16"
      MasterUsername: !Ref DBUsername
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref DBPassword
      MultiAZ: !Ref IsMultiAZ
      AvailabilityZone: !If [CheckIsMultiZone, !Ref AWS::NoValue, "us-east-1a"]
```

As you can see I have used the same concept you used. Can you test this template at your end to see if this is working or not. One issue I found in your template is that you are using AWS::NoValue while the correct format is !Ref AWS::NoValue as shown in my template. I believe this is the issue in your case. You can check the example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html#cfn-pseudo-param-novalue) .

Comment: I did not try your template (and I'm sure it will work), but you pointed out the formatting error, which is the incorrect use of the pseudo parameter `AWS::NoValue`. I corrected it to `!Ref AWS::NoValue` and it worked. Thanks for the help! Turns out it was a much simpler problem than expected.